# Migrating Apache,Wordpress and Media Wiki to docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, apache, phpbb

I am new to doker and web applicantions in general, and I am looking for a way to migrate a small website I host to docker.

Currently the website has Apache, serving 2 applications, a Worpdress Blog and a Phpbb Forum, plus a couple of HTML websites.

I was looking to learn how to migrate all of these applications and apply HA on it, by HA I mean, if the wordpress container goes down, it will not affect the phpbbforum and vice-versa.

Besides the offical docker documentation and Images documentation, were could I get more Information on how to do this ?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You will want to go through [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to edit and rephrase you question so it is not [off topic](/help/on-topic). Question seeking for documentation and references are not allowed on SO, nor vague or to broad questions without a specific programming concern. So yours has a high risk of attracting close votes.

Comment: Just so your not out of keywords to research... You will want to get familiar with the micro-service architecture, split your actual installation into (at least IMO) 6 containers (apache for wordpress, php-fpm for wordpress, mysql for wordpress, same goes for media-wiki). You might want an other apahce/nginx container that will reverse proxy to your different installations (or use something like traeffik...). You probably want to orchestrate all that with docker-compose... There is a lot more that will not fit in a comment but hopefully you have enough to start looking around.